# Is it possible to change html content without refreshing the page based on result from ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an upvote/downvote option on my website. I made it so that I can upvote an image without having to refresh the page thanks to ajax, however, because the page doesn't refresh, neither does the score of the image after the upvote. So even though my image has 1 upvote in my database, the page will display 0 upvotes until it is refreshed. I understand that I can return some data in the function(data), however I am not sure how to then display it on the website. This is the html content I want to change.

```
echo    "<div class='ratingNumber'>";
            if ($row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'] <= 0) {
                echo "<p>0</p>";
            } else {
                echo $row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'];
            }
echo    "</div>";
```

This is my ajax request.

```
$('.upvoteImage, .downvoteImage').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        var id = form.find("input[name='id']");
        var userId = form.find("input[name='userId']");
        var action = form.find("input[name='action']");
        var ratingNumber = form.parent('.upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer').find('.ratingNumber');

        $.post('../includes/voting.inc.php', {id: id.val(), userId: userId.val(), action: action.val()}, function(data){

        });

    });
```

And this is the part of my voting.inc.php file which contains the upvote/downvote logic. This is the part I want to return at the end and then somehow display it on the index page in the ratingNumber div.

```
$sql10 = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id='$imageId'";
        $result10 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql10);
        $getResult10 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result10);
        $upvotes = $getResult10['upvotes'];
        $downvotes = $getResult10['downvotes'];
        $finalVote = $upvotes-$downvotes;
        return $finalVote
```

Now I am not sure what exactly should I write in the function(data) in order to get $finalVote from the PHP file and then replace the current value of ratingNumber with the value from $finalVote. Any tips and pointers would really be helpful.

Comment: When you tell the server of the vote, it should return the newly calculated rating.  Then in the "on success" method of the ajax update the value using jQuery..

Comment: Well I was trying to alert(data) which I assumed would be the rating but instead I got absolutely nothing in the alert. Any idea why?

Comment: Your `voting.inc.php` needs to `echo` whatever you want to be sent to your `data` var

Comment: Depends on where the `alert` was.  If it is inside of your success handler then the server probably isn't sending it back properly.  Put a debug line in the success handler and interrogate the data better.  Also, try to step through the server side code and see exactly what is being sent back.

Comment: Echo-ing the information I wanted to be sent worked great. Thank.